# VS2015 Cordova Tools: xhr calls to http/https fail when switching from windows 8.1 to windows 10 in config.xml

Tags: cordova, winjs, windows-10, visual-studio-cordova

Very simply, I have been writing an app using the Cordova tools from VS 2015. It has worked fine with the default Windows 8.1 settings for Windows builds. However, I would like to take advantage of the dramatically increased speed in page navigation when I switch to Windows 10 in config.xml. However, as soon as I do this, all of my POSTs to remote urls with WinJS's xhr fail immediately with nothing other than the phrase "Security error".  The same code works fine when I switch it to Windows 8.1

Has anyone else experienced this?

I've tried switching from "remote mode" back to "local mode" by adding

to my config.xml, but it doesn't seem to affect this error.

*edit* The exact code I'm using (typescript):

```
var url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
 return WinJS.xhr({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": authorizationHeader
            },
            data: ""
        }).then((success) => { 

 },(error)=>{

 });
```

Generated AppxManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build">
  <!--
    THIS PACKAGE MANIFEST FILE IS GENERATED BY THE BUILD PROCESS.

    Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.

    For more information on package manifest files, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241727
  -->
  <Identity Name="redacted" Publisher="redacted" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="550b2480-3bd3-11e5-86b0-855663c85edc" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>redacted</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>L McPherson</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" Name="Windows.Universal" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="EN-US" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="io.cordova.myappfbb75e" StartPage="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html">
      <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="#464646" Description="CordovaApp" DisplayName="redacted" Square150x150Logo="images\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="images\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png" />
        <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="redacted" Square310x310Logo="images\Square310x310Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="images\Square71x71Logo.png" Wide310x150Logo="images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
        <uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
      </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>
  <build:Metadata>
    <build:Item Name="SharedGUID" Value="9ebdb27f-d75b-4d8c-b53f-7be4a1fe89f9" />
    <build:Item Name="CodeSharingProject" Value="248F659F-DAC5-46E8-AC09-60EC9FC95053" />
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudio" Version="14.0" />
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudioEdition" Value="Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015" />
    <build:Item Name="OperatingSystem" Version="10.0.10532.0 (th2_release.150822-1406)" />
    <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll" Version="14.0.23121.0" />
    <build:Item Name="ProjectGUID" Value="20968146-3a8e-4e05-96b7-33eedd330850" />
    <build:Item Name="OptimizingToolset" Value="ilc.exe" />
    <build:Item Name="TargetRuntime" Value="AppHost" />
    <build:Item Name="ilc.exe" Version="1.0.23117.00 built by: PROJECTNREL" />
    <build:Item Name="MakePri.exe" Version="10.0.10240.16384 (th1.150709-1700)" />
  </build:Metadata>
</Package>
```

Comment: In config.xml, is the URL for your remote server included in the domain access list (<access origin=...> elements in the XML)?

Comment: I do not have a specific URL included in the access lists. It is still using wildcards (http://*/*). Will try with a specific URL.

Comment: Doesn't help.  I'm debugging within winjs even and the error is thrown as soon as the XMLHttpRequest open method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out finally.  I believe part of my problem was that I was using pieces of code/html from an older project and not using the defaults that a new project would provide.  In any case, there is a new line in the head of the index.html file that Cordova generates:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

If I'm not mistaken, Windows 8.1 does not evaluate this line.  However, Windows 10 **does**.  I got an error when I tried to insert 'connect-src' as one of the directives, so I just modified the default-src directive to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://api.twitter.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Since I want to get content from https://api.twitter.com, I had to specifically include it as allowed.

Also, I am not sure if it helped or did nothing, but I excluded the winstore-jscompat.js shim.  This is not needed for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In general the XHR code you are using should work. I added this example to show XHR post data is working. I am using WinJS 4.0 http://try.buildwinjs.com/download/GetWinJS/, although any new version should work fine. Did you upgrade the version of WinJS you are using?

```
function success(evt) {

}

function error(evt) {

}

WinJS.xhr({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    data: JSON.stringify({ myData: "postDataStringValue" })
}).then(success, error);
```

Comment: Mine looks pretty much like that except using typescript. I'm using WinJS 4.3 I think... the latest. I'd this in Cordova because this works fine when the target OS is windows 8.1, just not when it's windows 10.

Comment: Can you copy the appxmanifest.xml that is produced when the project is built? I am wondering if there is an error with the application capabilities...

Comment: I thought about that, but all I could think to look for was the internet capabilities and I think it's fine.  I'm adding it to the main question.